# Calling a method from my MainActivity

Tags: android, button, methods, onclick, android-dialogfragment

I've desperatly tried everything on Internet to be able to call my 
`thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(View view)`, when user click my `Delete Button` MainActivity, but nothing works. The button gives no reaction.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

private ArrayList<item> items= new ArrayList<>();


public void addItemToListView(Item item){
    this.items.add(item);
}

public void deleteItem(int position){
    items.remove(position);
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getIdOfItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, content;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        title= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        content= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(null == convertView){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        viewHolder.header.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item item= getItem(position);
    viewHolder.header.setText(item.title);
    viewHolder.bodyText.setText(item.content);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**MyDialogForDeletingAItem class**

```
 public class MyDialogForDeletingAItem extends DialogFragment 
    implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button delete;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deleteDialog, null);
    delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view; }

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
if (view.getId() == R.id.delete) {
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
            main.thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(view, //This is where the problem is... 
//I don't know what to pass in here);
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements       
    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    Adapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        adapter= new Adapter();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

public void longItemClick(View view) {
    DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogForDeletingAItem();
    dialog.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialogForDeletingAItem");
    thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(view);

}
  public void deleteRow(int position){
        adapter.delete(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(View view, int position){
deleteRow(position);
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DELETE"
        android:id="@+id/delete" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp" />


at se.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity.thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton
(MainActivity.java:100)
at se.example.android.myapplication.DeleteAndEdit.onClick(DeleteAndEdit.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `onClick(View view)` method creates a new instance of your `MainActivity` while you need to use already loaded activity instance.

call like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
if (view.getId() == R.id.delete) {
      ((MainActivity) getActivity()).thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(view);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Now the toast works. 
But I guess I can't put a second parameter inside my onClick method right? Cause the purpose of having the thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(View view) was to call my deleteRow(position), which would delete my item inside the listview. 
But to get the position that's declared in my MainActivity, I need to do this:
thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(View view, int position){
deleteRow(position)
}
But then the MyDialogForDeletingAItem.java tells me that I have to put a second (int) parameter when calling my method inside my onClick method. Any idea what to do?

Comment: second parameter is from fragment only Right?

Comment: No, it's in  my Adapter.java class.
Please look at the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `deleteRow()` method should take View as a parameter

```
public void deleteRow(View view)
```

> public static final int onClick
>
> Added in API level 4 Name of the method in this View's context to
>   invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public
>   method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if
>   you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void
>   sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).
>
> Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n'
>   or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

[onClick](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick)

Comment: I took out my first parameter deleteRow(int position) and replaced with yours. 
    public void deleteItem(View view){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
Still nothing happens

Comment: If I call the method inside my OnItemLongClick...
It works. But then the purpose of having the onClick method is gone, since it's calling deleteRow(View view) when I hold my finger on an item, and not when I actually click the button "Delete"

Comment: `public class MyDialogForDeletingAItem extends DialogFragment 
    implements View.OnClickListener` - I don't see an onClick method implemented. Is this your complete code? You have to pick one way of listening for click... either through `onClick` implemented via `OnClickListener` or through the xml declaration of `onClick:deleteRow`

Comment: I've also tried this inside my MyDialogForDeletingAItem.class.
   
 @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
if (view.getId() == R.id.delete) {
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
            main.thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton(view);
}
But this time I get following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

This class extends DialogFragment and not Activity. 

Could this be a reason why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity where are you referencing your`thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton` ?? Try to add `android:onClick="thisIsAMethodJustToTryOutMyButton"` in your xml file

Comment: In my MainActivity longItemClick(View view).
What this does is instantly calling the Toast. 
I also changed my onClick in my .xml too 
thisIsAMethodJustTo...., but still the same error. 
In other words, it doesn't work when I click on the button.